# is it 0 degree or 0 degrees outside?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, grammatical-number

This is in relation to the question "It's “1 degrees” or is it “1 degree” outside?". I have heard many people say that it is zero degrees outside. Is this correct, or is it 0 degree? The latter simply doesn't sound right.

Comment: Zero is treated as plural in (AFAIK) all circumstances. I have zero apples, zero chips and zero cares

Comment: There are no **cars** on the road.

Comment: @BlessedGeek Great example. +1.

Comment: I don't care how you say it, it's minus 5 right now and I'm freezing.

Comment: @BlessedGeek: There are no Santa Clauses?

Comment: Will noun phrases and adverbial clauses do?

Comment: @RahulNarain  Or, there is no Santa Claus!

Comment: @BlessedGeek Or, There is no car on the road!

Comment: +WS2 There isn't any car in the garage = it has capacity for only one car, or that you expect to see only one car. The is no car on road = there is capacity for only one one car on the road or that you expect to see only one car on the road.

Answer (score 8):

"One degree" is correct, as is "zero degrees".  It grates on my inner geek that a quantity of zero is pluralized, but that's the way it is.

Comment: Don't think of it as a _plural_ as such; think of it instead as a ‘non-singular’. It applies to everything that is not precisely equal to one, whether it's higher or lower.

Comment: + 1, I didn't know that. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Janus: everything except *"one half" or "a half",* but maybe that counts as a singular half-mile.  *"One half mile",* but  *"0.5 miles".*

Comment: Indeed, it's one half-mile, or one-half of *a mile*. Either way, it's a single mile that's being halved; hence the singular usage.

Comment: But that applies to all fractions, not just one half: _two-thirds of a mile_, _three-quarters of an hour_.

Comment: @aeismall it is one third of a mile, two thirds of a mile, one quarter of an hour, three quarters of an hour.

Comment: @Peter, ‘half’ when used like that basically functions like an adjective, so even though the semantic meaning of the mile changes, it is still a singular. You can also speak of a double mile, which is the same as two miles, but it is grammatically singular. Only numerals (including decimals) and determiners can force a noun to non-singularity; adjectives do not (_vel sim_).

Comment: Let's not forget -1 degrees.

Comment: Let's do; it'd be "negative one degree", or "one degree below zero", or (if you want to make peoples' eyes twitch) "minus one degree".

Comment: If 0 degrees offends, just use 273 Kelvin. For similarly geeky reasons there are no degrees Kelvin

Answer (score 0):

From the *OED*,

> Each of the marks denoting degrees of temperature on the scale of a thermometer, or the interval between two successive marks.

This usage of degree literally meant to measure against a thermometer containing markings that were called *degrees*. Thus, zero degrees is when the liquid inside did not rise to any of the marks above. one degree is to say the liquid inside rose to one mark.

Admittedly, we have now greatly expanded the concept of how we conceive of temperature, but such is the origin.